# How to call javascript functions from flash ExternallInterface on release action

Tags: javascript, actionscript, externalinterface

My HTML is:

```
<object width="800" height="600"
    classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/
    pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0">
        <param name="SRC" value="intros/01/intro.swf" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#999900" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
        <embed src="intros/01/intro.swf" width="800" height="600"></embed>
</object>
```

I have this code on my button Flash:

```
on (release) {
    import flash.external.*;
    var isAvailable:Boolean = ExternalInterface.available;
    if( isAvailable ) {
        ExternalInterface.call( "sample" );
    }
}
```

and javascript/jquery is:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function(){

    function sample() {

       alert( 'message' );
    }
});
```

what am I doing wrong? I'm using action script 2.0. When I test it in flash, for example, to know if isAvalaible variable is true, it really is... it's true.

Answer (score 1):

don't put sample() inside of  (document).ready()

It isn't in scope anymore. It should work fine as long as its outside of ready.

Also, since its a function declaration, you don't need it inside of ready anyway.

Comment: I've tried with a simple alert() like: ExternalInterface.call( "alert", "message" ); but It doesn't work

Comment: try it like this:
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
            ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Hello World!");

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a while since I've done AS2, but I see two things here that I'd change.  First, get rid of the import statement on your button code.

```
var isAvailable:Boolean = flash.external.ExternalInterface.available;
```

Then, the jquery you have is structured as an anonymous function.  Try this instead on your webpage:

```
function sample(){...}
$(sample);
```

Then, when jQuery is initialized, it will call sample, and sample will be available from elsewhere.

Comment: I've tried your code... but it doesn't work. I guess my error is in on(release) event...

Comment: Did you confirm that your error is in the on(release) event with trace statements?  Did you get rid of the import statement in that function?

Comment: Yeah I did. isAvailable var returns true in flash console. If I get the .call object it returns null, I guess that's why I am testing in flash and html and javascript are not in...

Comment: If you're testing this locally, you have to set up the Flash as trusted in the Global Security Settings Panel online.  http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: OK... If I test it in firefox... an alert is showing "One object wants to communicate...." and the object appears as null. I think it's about security...

Comment: It probably is a security issue.  That panel has burned me a number of times in the past.  Are you able to test it via http?

Answer (score 0):

Thank u all. I've found the solution.... It was about security and permissions of flash player... Your suggestions of code were part of the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this post useful for you:
http://www.kirupa.com/flash/calling_javascript_flash_using_as3.htm